# PHP: Define a variable within two or more ranges with alternatives to array_merge()?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, append, range

I have a case where I need to check if a variable is in array and since more and more data is added I may need to assign two or more ranges of numbers to a variable for the check.

I tried appending another range to the variable and I also tried `array_merge()`.

```
$x = range(0,10);
$y = range(15,30);
$z = array_merge($x, $y);
print_r($z);
```

Is there a more convenient way to keep the variable name `$x` rather than having to add each additional range with another variable (`$y`) then merging it with `$x` and assigning yet another variable (`$z`) to the `array_merge()`?

I need something like `$x` is in range of both numbers from 0 to 10 but also  from 15 to 30 without the extra math?

```
$x = range(0,10);
$x .= range(15,30);
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the original `range()` with the new range, and assign it back to `$x`. You do not have to give it a new name for every new value it gets, you can overwrite the value instead.

```
$x = range(0,10);
$x = array_merge($x, range(15,30));
print_r($x);
```